# Saving multiple worksheets to a single pdf?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to extract a selection of worksheets from a workbook; worksheets whose names contain the string: "STRINGY", and export those worksheets as *one single pdf*. The code below creates a blank pdf.

```
Sub Test()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, sht.Name, "STRINGY") > 0 Then
        Sheets(sht.Name).Select Replace:=False
    End If
Next sht
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\File.pdf"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were along the right lines, but didn't use the `Selection` correctly. The following should do what you need:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

  Dim arrSheets() As String
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer

  i = 0
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, sht.Name, "STRINGY") > 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve arrSheets(i)
      arrSheets(i) = sht.Name
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next sht

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arrSheets).Select

  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                  Filename:="C:\File.pdf", _
                                  OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Basically, you need to add the sheets whose name contain your search string in an array and select them all at the same time. Then use that selection as the basis for the export to PDF.

I added the `OpenAfterPublish` export option so that the file opens in your PDF reader after export; it's not a requirement.

The above code has been successfully tested with Excel 2010, but can't be certain it'll work in Excel 2007 or previous. Notice that *an error will occur if the PDF add-in is not currently installed.* If that's the case, you can find it at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but the pdfs are coming out blank, not sure why? Did they work for you?
EDIT: The PDF seems to print whatever was selected before the script was run, even if I use
``Application.CutCopyMode = False``

Comment: @quantum285: Yes, the code worked for me. Perhaps your data is outside the page area? To test it, I put some dummy text in cell A1 of some sheets whose name contained the string "STRINGY" (2 of the 3 sheets in my test workbook) and when the pdf was generated the dummy text that I entered was there.

Comment: That's what I tried as well, frustrating... I've checked Page Break view and the dummy text is all that's in the print area anyway.
It literally only prints the cell that was selected before the macro was run if that's any help

Comment: @quantum285: Silly mistake in my code (edited my answer). You need to call `ExportAsFixedFormat` on the **`ActiveSheet`** not on the `Selection`. Seems counter-intuitive, but it'll work as expected now.

Comment: That's amazing, yeah it does seem a bit counter-intuitive but I guess I just need to recalibrate my intuition. Thanks!